# console img src always undefined

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I know that there is many post about this topic but i dont know why it keeps return me "undefined".

html:

```
<div class="gridShortlist active" onclick="shortlist('1');">
    <img src="../../images/shortlisted.png"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
function shortlist(intValue){
    if (intValue == 1){
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        console.log(src);

    }
    else if (intValue == 0){
        alert("deactive");
    }
}
```

I would like to return the src value of img, but not sure why it will only return undefined.
Anyone can help to correct me?

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Based on that snippet, it looks like `this` is referring to the `window`.

Comment: isnt the "this" should be referring to div.gridShortlist since the onclick function is on it?

Comment: You should avoid binding onClick inline — try using jQuery's `.click()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `this` with the click, we can make sure the right `this` is used. Also, passing 1 as a number instead of a string is probably a good idea since you compare to a number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="gridShortlist active" onclick="shortlist(this, 1);">
    <img src="../../images/shortlisted.png"/>
</div>

<script>
function shortlist(_this, intValue){
    if (intValue == 1){
        var src = $(_this).find('img').attr('src');
        console.log(src);

    }
    else if (intValue == 0){
        alert("deactive");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: document]

You can check this link [reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/2cj11z8v/)

```js
var ele=document.getElementById("id1");
ele.onclick  =function (){
    var intValue=1
    if (intValue == 1){
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
        alert(src);
    }
    else if (intValue == 0){
        alert("deactive");
    }
};
```

```css
div{
    display:block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridShortlist active" id="id1" >
    <img src="../../images/shortlisted.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple jquery solution for the same by the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gridShortlist', function (intValue) {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(src);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz74y09L/)